# How do I apply string.Format to SQL Results?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, string.format, intersystems-cache

In my application, I am querying the database, and would like to apply `string.Format("{0:n}")` to my results, so that the results have commas and decimals.

However, I am having trouble getting it to work correctly. The code compiles, and everything works fine, but the numbers are not formatted how I want them.

Here is my current code:

```
using (CacheConnection myConnection = new CacheConnection())
{
    myConnection.ConnectionTimeout = 9999;
    myConnection.ConnectionString = monthPropStruct.connectionString;
    myConnection.Open();

    using (CacheCommand myCommand = new CacheCommand(sqlTest, myConnection))
    {
        myCommand.CommandTimeout = 9999;
        using (CacheDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                myWriter = new StreamWriter(myParameters.fullSaveDirectory, true);
                myWriter.WriteLine("Amount: $" + string.Format("{0:n}", myReader[myReader.GetOrdinal("total_amt")]));
                myWriter.Close();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

The current result I am getting is "245687" or whatever, but I would like it display as 245,678.00

Comment: convert your value to decimal first.

Comment: @Rakitić, yup that's exactly what I needed to do. Thanks!

Comment: you can also use `string.Format("{0:C}"` and remove the `$` from the string `"Amount: $"` as the **$** will be added automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String formatting  will work for numeric value, whereas your code `myReader[myReader.GetOrdinal("total_amt")])` will return an object. Convert your value to numeric and then apply formatting like:

```
Convert.ToDecimal((myReader[myReader.GetOrdinal("total_amt")]))
```

Or use:

```
pReader.GetDecimal(pReader.GetOrdinal("total_amt"))
```

*(I believe you have `Decimal` type for money, in any case it should be the one used for Money.)*

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH. Haha. I feel dumb. Thanks so much!